# display username in dashboard after login

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, authentication

I want to display username in my dashboard after successful login.I have api running on serparate server where it performs login.I am not using passport.js .

```
app.post('/users/login', function (req, res) {

    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var form = {

        email,
        password

    }
    request.post({
        url: "https://www.mywebsite.com/users/login",
        headers: {
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        },
        body: form,
        json: true

    }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error)
        console.log('body:', body.errmsg);
        console.log(body);
        if (body.user) {
            res.redirect('/dashboard')
        } else {
            res.render('login', {
                name,
                email,
                password
            })
        }

    })
})
```

How will it be possible to display username from which i successfully logged in.
Something like this.

```
dashboard.ejs
Welcome user <%=name%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying on EJS template engine you need to use

```
res.render('dashboard',{'user' : body.user} );
```

and in `dashboard.js`:

```
Welcome user <%=user.name%>
```